# Can't accept answer

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, accepting

Someone answered my question, but there is no checkmark to accept the answer. I've been unable to find out if I need more reputation to do this, if I'm missing something, or if something is wrong.

[Here is the question in question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132062/loading-lineno-changes-spacing-in-document)

Comment: It doesn't appear that the question actually has an answer, rather there is a _comment_ that answers the question.  If/when karlkoeller turns his comment into an answer, you will then be able to accept it. This is assuming that there wasn't an answer that has been deleted since you posted the question.  Compare what you see in that question, to [this question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111180/webpage-without-author-using-the-title-can-make-a-very-long-apa-citation) to see the difference.

Comment: Related/Duplicates [Adding the “accepted” mark to a question or to a comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3683/15717) and [What if a comment answers a question?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1731/15717)

Answer (score 3):

[Scott H.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/cant-accept-answer#comment13004_3798) correctly answered your question; only answers can be accepted.  [The network ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196497/1438) that comments be reserved clarifying the content or suggesting improvements to a post.  Answers (even partial, comment-sized answers) should not be hidden in the comments.

Comment: We have had substantial discussion about the phenomenon of potential answers in comments which is a strategy used with great success here.  Please see [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238). Overall we have no questions  that have been answered in comments and receive no answer. Usually answers in comments are turned into answers.

Comment: I've edited slightly to make it clear the link is network-wide: I hope this is OK